# Android element.getAttributes() not working

Tags: android, xml, attributes

My XML:

```
<records>
   <employee id="0">
      <name>Sairamkrishna</name>
      <surname>Mammahe</surname>
      <salary>50000</salary>
   </employee>

   <employee id="1">
      <name>Gopal </name>
      <surname>Varma</surname>
      <salary>60000</salary>
   </employee>

   <employee id="2">
      <name>Raja</name>
      <surname>Hr</surname>
      <salary>70000</salary>
   </employee>
</records>
```

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <nList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nList.item(i);

    if ((node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE))
    {
        Element element2 = (Element) node;
        String attr = element2.getAttribute("id");
        Log.d("result", attr);
        if (attr == "1") {
            **NOT WORKING**
        }
    }
```

Return Logs:

```
Log.d:

    D/result: 0
    D/result: 1
    D/result: 2
```

If I can not get into the question in any way, why?

Not working: `if`, `element.getAttributes();`, and `attr==1`.

How can draw values according to their attributes in XML? I have not managed it somehow. I do not get any errors in the "eger" question, but do not enter, I can get the id attributes if I query without Logs if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not let you compare Strings like that.

You should do it like this:

```
if (attr.equals("1")) { 

}
```